# Make webform submissions non-editable?

Tags: webforms

I have created a web site with a bunch of Webforms used to collect data from surveyors.  My client is interested in having the ability to make individual submissions non-editable by the surveyor while not removing the ability for surveyors to edit their own submissions generally.  In other words, she wants the surveyors to be able to edit their submissions at her direction, but once she considers the submission complete, she wants to lock it down and prevent further editing, partly to prevent confusion if the surveyor perhaps has two or three different webforms they are working on.

Do you know any way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the "Content Access" module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access

Once your client wants to "Lock down" the webform, she can do so within the Role Based and Per Content Node access control settings.

Hope this helps.
-Wrench